# ¿Cómo muestro una lista de archivos de texto de una carpeta en un JTextArea?

Tags: java

He creado un array de tipo String que contenga la lista de los archivos en la ruta especificada, pero nada parece añadir el contenido de la variable en la caja de texto.

```
public void MostrarArchivos(){
    String ubicacion = "D:\\Proyects\\BDP";
    String archivos;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    File carpeta = new File(ubicacion);
    File [] lista = carpeta.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
        if(lista[i].isFile()){
            archivos = lista[i].getName();
            sb.append(archivos);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

    }
    jTextArea2.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que estás intentando hacer para añadir el texto?

Comment: Este es el último de varios códigos que he intentado usar.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `jTextArea2.setText(...)` por `jTextArea2.append(...)`.